# Req.Params.Token returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

In my code, I have my registration page send out a verification email once the form is filled out and submitted. They receive the link to their email to verify it, and the link should trigger a request to change the account from inactive to active. I’m not sure if I did something wrong here but the code is as follows.

Where the user ends up after clicking the link.

```
app.get('/verify-email', (req, res, next) => {
console.log('req.params.token: ' + req.params.token);
changeAccountStatus(req.params.token);
res.redirect('/login');});
```

The function that the token is passed through.

```
function changeAccountStatus(verifyingToken){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE VerificationToken= ?', [verifyingToken], function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log('results from WHERE VerificationToken ' + results[0]);
        connection.query('UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET STATUS = ? WHERE VerificationToken = ?', ['Active', verifyingToken], function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log('results from UPDATE ACCOUNTS ' + results[0]);
            }            
        });        
    }
});};
```

In the app.get(‘/verify-email’) method, the token returns undefined. I’m not sure why, I know that I get a token because an email is send and the token is pushed to the db.

Comment: Your route has no [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). How are you making the request from the client-side? How are you passing the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change req.params.token to req.query.token. Everything was resolved that this point, but make sure that your functions are setup correctly too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your token is in params. As normally, token suppose to be in headers.
try `req.headers.authorization` instead of `req.params.token` to check if it is there.

Comment: My money's on `req.query.token`

Comment: That has also returned undefined.

Comment: Phil was correct about the query.token. Phil, if you post a comment explaining why, I’ll upvote it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonD your question can be closed due to a _typo_. It doesn't need an answer